# Repeat countdown timer for game

Tags: android

I'm creating a game where the user will have X seconds to make his move every turn, so I need to show the amount of seconds remaining and control the game.

If the user makes his move before countdown is complete, the countdown is cancelled and started again as a new turn. And if the countdown ends before the user makes his move, the game is ended.

Important: each second (timer tick event) a sound is played and this shouldn't affect the timer interval.

How can I do this? Should I use a Timer, a CountDownTimer or something else?﻿

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CountDown Timer as your requirement........

here you can control timer calling Below code...

```
if (!timerHasStarted) { 
           countDownTimer.start(); 
           timerHasStarted = true; 
           startB.setText("STOP"); 
          } else { 
           countDownTimer.cancel(); 
           timerHasStarted = false; 
           startB.setText("RESTART"); 
          }
```

follow below link..

http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use CountDownTimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //Play your audio here
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //Trigger the game end action
     }
  }.start();
```

call `cancel()` to stop the timer.

Reference: [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: If you run this code you may notice that the first tick event seems to have run in less than 1 second.

Comment: @Juliano Nunes Silva Oliveira: CountDownTimer is not precise. 
Please refer to these: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810416/android-countdowntimer-shows-1-for-two-seconds
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824068/how-come-millisuntilfinished-cannot-detect-exact-countdowntimer-intervals

Comment: I'm affraid that decreasing the interval to just 100ms would cause some kind of overhead. I'll make some tests.