# Why is CountDownTimer not accurate

Tags: android, android-alarms, countdowntimer, foreground-service

I have 2 CountDownTimer objects in my app, that count the time to next event constantly as the app is running.

So today I debugged it, and found out that the timer is not accurate at all, I have given it an interval of 1 hour, starting at 9:00 am, and now 14:04 was when the next event fired. whole 4 mins late, and it is getting more and more with each event.

So should I use the CountDownTimer for such task, or I should just make an if check in it's `onTick()` method, where every second I will check for fixed time passed since the previous event, then reset the time for after 1 hour?

I can't do these tasks with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), since all these things are happening in `foreground service` , and as much as I know, Alarms will be killed if the users swipes the app away from the running apps menu

Comment: did you see [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824068/how-come-millisuntilfinished-cannot-detect-exact-countdowntimer-intervals) - Q. Have you got this running on its own thread? or just on the main thread?

Comment: CountDownTimer is very imprecise. Check this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6811744/2904294

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android CountDownTimer shows 1 for two seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810416/android-countdowntimer-shows-1-for-two-seconds)